# What can we say about the order of the group which is generated by $\langle u,v\rangle$

Tags: group-theory

If a group $G$ is generated by $\langle u,v\rangle$ and order of $u$ is less than or equal to $4$ and order of $v$ is less than or equal to $3$. Then what can we say about the order of the group? It is also given that $uv$=$v^2u^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $v$ has order $1$, we conclude $u=u^2$, so $u=1$ and ultimately $G=1$.
If $v$ has order $2$, we conclude $uv=u^2$, hence $u=v$ and $G=C_2$.
So assume $v$ has order $3$.
If $u$ has order $1$, we find $G=1$ again; and if $u$ has order $2$, we find $u=v$, contradiction;
if $u$ has order $4$, we find $u^2v=uv^2u^2=v^2u^2vu^2=v^2uv^2=vu^2v$, contradiction.

So we are left with $u,v$ both of order $3$.
Then we have $uv=(uv)^{-1}$; this allows $u=v^{-1}$ as one solution, which makes $G=C_3$. Alternatively, we could have $G=\langle(1\,2\,3),(2\,3\,4)=A_4$.